# How to provide password using sudo

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, svn

I am trying to run the following command

```
sh "sudo mkdir -p ${devEnvTmp}/distcc"
```

and it requires sudo, but when I do sudo I get this error-

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

I dont know how to use `-S` to give password, could you please help me with this

I tried this `sh "sudo -S mkdir -p ${devEnvTmp}/distcc"` but this give me error-

```
Password:
sudo: no password was provided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo -S` read from standard input.

Try with:

```bash
sh "echo 'password' | sudo -S mkdir -p ${devEnvTmp}/distcc"
```